# Does it make sense to move to SolrCloud architecture from Solr Master-Slave architecture when you have just one shard?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I think that SolrCloud architecture really shines when indexes are divided into multiple shards. Besides this point, I don't see any valid reason to go from Solr Master-Slave architecture to SolrCloud architecture if you have only one shard. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

SolrCloud has additional benefits, among which:

1. you can send docs to index to any of the nodes (in master/slave  you need to send them to master)
2. you can do a number on actions on the shard, like split it etc
3. you can setup [cross data center replication](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62687462#CrossDataCenterReplication(CDCR)-CDCRConfiguration). Not sure you could achieve something similar by manually configuring master/slave...even if you did, it would be much more complex
4. you can use [Streaming Expressions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions)
5. and more I am probably forgetting